# Chartjs multiple barcharts , the first data will offset over view

Tags: jquery, chart.js

When multiple bar graphs are juxtaposed, the first group of data on the left will exceed the horizon.

like the [pic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A6C5ggR-NyntqDgDk5ZqewqrHV8Vx0-k/view?usp=sharing):

this is my env:
ec2 , apache2 , php7 , laravel 5.2

my jQuery like this:

```
 datasets: [
            {
             label: 'sale_revenue',
             backgroundColor: 'rgba(109,127,200,0.7)',
             borderColor: 'rgb(46,46,200)',
             data: sale_revenue0,
             yAxisID: 'left-y-axis'
             },....
```

more than 3 bars.

I want it show those 3 first datas.
but, it over view.

Answer (score 0):

我從其他地方發現了這個問題的解答，
而且我同時想出了兩個方法來解決這個問題。

如有人遇到相同的問題，可以參考這篇

[uneven distribution of xaxis time scale with 'autoSkip:true' and maxTicksLimit #3277](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3277)

方法一：

不使用 type= time

```js
options: {
          scales: {
                   xAxes: [{
                            // type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                   unit: 'month'
                                },
                            distribution: 'series'
                          }],
                          ...
```

方法二：

在時間軸的前後加上一組時間序列，值為 0

[圖片](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RNWOADO-vtEd_eyOl48_n81N86z2-Emy/view?usp=sharing)